# Using ggplot2 to graph counts of multiple x variables together

Tags: r, excel, csv, ggplot2

I'm using an csv of survey data. Each row is an individual survey. One of the questions asked is "What activities do you take part in at the beach?". There is a column for each of the 12 activities listed. If an interviewer said they took part in an activity, the csv has a 1 and if they did not it has a 2. I want to create a barplot in ggplot2 showing how many people participate in all activities, and then use cross tabs (gender, location, age, etc.) for fill later on.

I've done this in base r:

```
swim.all.13=table(b13$actswim)
surf.all.13=table(b13$actsurf)
walk.all.13=table(b13$actwalk)
relax.all.13=table(b13$actrelx)
shell.all.13=table(b13$actshell)
picnic.all.13=table(b13$actpic)
sun.all.13=table(b13$actsun)
read.all.13=table(b13$actread)
fish.all.13=table(b13$actfish)
work.all.13=table(b13$actwork)
eat.all.13=table(b13$acteat)

act.all.13.test=cbind(swim.all.13,surf.all.13,walk.all.13,relax.all.13,shell.all.13,picnic.all.13,sun.all.13,read.all.13,fish.all.13,work.all.13,eat.all.13)
act.all.13=act.all.13.test[2,]

barplot(act.all.13,xlab="Activity",ylab="NUmber of Responses",names.arg=" ",legend=c("Swim", "Surf", "Walk", "Relax", "Shell", "Picnic", "Sun", "Read", "Fish", "Work", "Eat"),main="What activities do you engage in while at the beach?")
```

Which gives me the table I am looking for, but looks like complete garbage. I prefer graphing in ggplot2, which is what the rest of the survey data is graphed in.

[Screenshot of CSV I'm working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6Oo1.png)

Comment: can you please provide an example dataset?

Comment: Screenshot of the csv I'm working with. http://imgur.com/a/7yfQW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited based on OP Comment:

How about

```
data %>% 
  gather(activity, ct, ActSwim:acteat) %>% 
  filter(ct == 1) %>% 
  count(activity) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(activity, n)) + geom_barplot(stat = "identity")
```

Basically converts the data into a tidy dataset which is tall rather than wide, filters just for 1 as the value and uses dplyr::count() to aggregate and feed into plot.

Edit: to facet by Gender:

```
data %>% 
  gather(activity, ct, ActSwim:acteat) %>% 
  filter(ct == 1) %>% 
  count(activity, gender) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(activity, n)) + 
     geom_barplot(stat = "identity") + 
     facet_wrap(~gender, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer my question. I'm trying to get counts of each variable (how many people picnic at the beach, how many people surf) and compare them to each other. I don't need whether or not an individual does all activities.

Comment: Ah, ok. So if the data has 1 for participated and 2 for not, why do some values have, say, 7?

Comment: The first column (VisBeau) is a part of a different question, so it not part of the plot I'm trying to create. I'm only concerned with columns that being with "act".

Comment: ok, have made a light tweak! try that....

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is there a way to facet wrap this dataset based on a different factor (gender or location, for instance)?

Comment: Sure. See edit!

Comment: Is there anyway to transform the counts to proportions in order to correct for the fact that there are not equal numbers of each gender?